# Web access to tableau server installed on google cloud instance with centos 7 as OS

Tags: linux, web, centos, tableau-api

I created VM (virtual machine) instance on Google Cloud with CentOS 7 as OS to install Tableau Server and http access to it using set of commands from online free video. After successful installation I try to use web browser to get an access to Tableau Configuration and I see nothing but an error message "Connection took too long".

Pretty much I didn't do anything else yet because on video everything is right and smooth. Already asked owner of video but who knows how busy he is and if consider it his responsibility to answer the questions.

```
sudo -i
yum update -y
sudo yum install wget -y
wget https://downloads.tableau.com/tssoftware/tableau-server-2018-2-0.x86_64.rpm
chmod 777 tableau-server-2018-2-0.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install tableau-server-2018-2-0.x86_64.rpm
adduser admin
passwd admin
usermod -aG wheel admin
systemctl status firewalld.service
systemctl disable firewalld.service
systemctl stop firewalld.service
su - admin
cd /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/scripts.20182.18.0627.2230/
sudo ./initialize-tsm --accepteula
sudo usermod -G tsmadmin -a admin
source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh
```

After many starts and stops and checking the Tableau Server application status I still not able to have web access to configuration page.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the [Linux install docs](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/setup.htm).  You are missing a few steps like registration and configuring the initial node.

Also, you shouldn't install as `su - admin`.  You want to install in the user space using sudo.

When you do get the server up and running you should be able to run `tsm status` and see that Tableau Server is running.  If you still cannot reach the server after that then there is probably something going on with the networking with the GCP settings.